# Embedding multiple images in one Class file, in Haxe 3

Tags: flash, meta-tags, embedded-resource, haxe, flashdevelop

I'm trying to embed several images (the manual way with `@:bitmap(...)` for each PNGs) in the same class file.

But, when I come to use the PNG, I keep getting `Class not found : assets._NameOfImageClass_`

Do I need to import the *same-named* Class as the *.hx file they're all tossed in, first?

(**Example:** If they are all defined in: `assets/Assets.hx`, do I need to `import assets.Assets;` before I can use `new ICON_FILE();` or should I be able to just use `import assets.ICON_FILE;`?)

I'm using FlashDevelop, this is to target Flash.

*(Note: I would prefer not to use an OpenFL solution for this)*

Answer (score 0):

You just need the line `import assets.Assets;`

The class with assets.

```
package mypack ;

import flash.media.Sound;

@:sound("assets/sound/Hit_Hurt.wav") class Hit_Hurt extends flash.media.Sound { }
@:sound("assets/sound/Jump2.wav") class Jump extends flash.media.Sound { }
@:sound("assets/sound/Laser_Shoot.wav") class Laser_Shoot extends flash.media.Sound { }

class SoundLib
{
    private static var _sounds:Array<Sound> = [ new Hit_Hurt(), new Jump(), new Laser_Shoot() ];


    public static function play( index:Int ):Void
    {
        _sounds[ index ].play();
    }

}
```

The main class.

```
package ;

import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.Lib;
import flash.media.Sound;
import mypack.SoundLib;

class Main 
{


    static function main() 
    {
        var stage = Lib.current.stage;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        var tmp:Sound = new Laser_Shoot();
        tmp.play();
    }

}
```